# No data found error in PLSQL while calling a procedure inside another plsql block

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying execute the below block but an error as "No data found" even though there is data available in the table to process :

this block is trying to call the another user defined procedure and passing the parameters from the variable:

```
DECLARE
   v_file_name   regression_status.file_name%TYPE;
   v_run_no      regression_status.run_no%TYPE;
   v_stream_id   regression_status.stream_id%TYPE;
   v_job_id      regression_status.job_id%TYPE;
   str           VARCHAR2 (100) := 'A ,B ,C ,D';
   v_count       VARCHAR2 (100);
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (status)
     INTO v_count
     FROM regression_status
    WHERE status = 'R';

   LOOP
      BEGIN
         FOR i IN (    SELECT TRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (str,
                                                   '[^,]+',
                                                   1,
                                                   LEVEL))
                                 l
                         FROM DUAL
                   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (str, ',') + 1)
         LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (i.l);

            SELECT tbl.run_no,
                   TBL.JOB_ID,
                   TBL.STREAM_ID,
                   TBL.FILE_NAME
              INTO v_run_no,
                   v_job_id,
                   v_stream_id,
                   v_file_name
              FROM REGRESSION_STATUS tbl
                   INNER JOIN (  SELECT job_id, MIN (run_no) min_run_no
                                   FROM REGRESSION_STATUS
                                  WHERE status = 'R'
                               GROUP BY job_id) tbl1
                      ON tbl1.job_id = tbl.job_id
             WHERE     tbl1.min_run_no = tbl.run_no
                   AND tbl.file_name LIKE '%' || i.l || '%';

            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
                  'script executing for file : '
               || v_file_name
               || ' '
               || v_stream_id
               || ' '
               || v_run_no
               || ' '
               || v_job_id
               || ' ');

            MAIN_PKG.PROC (v_run_no,
                           'v_job_id',
                           SUBSTR (v_stream_id, 0, 2),
                           'v_file_name');

            UPDATE regression_status
               SET status = 'S', end_time = SYSDATE
             WHERE file_name = v_file_name;

            COMMIT;
         END LOOP;
      END;

      EXIT WHEN v_count <= 0;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: You have a number of implicit cursors in there - any one of them could throw NO_DATA_FOUND.  Put some debug into the procedure and find out exactly where the exception is thrown.  Once you know which statement returns no rows you can start to investigate why

Comment: MAIN_PKG.PROC (v_run_no,
                           'v_job_id',
                           SUBSTR (v_stream_id, 0, 2),
                           'v_file_name');

this line is throwing an error

Comment: In that case the NO_DATA_FOUND exception is being thrown from within the other package.  Is that something you have access to?  If so then you need to perform the same debug in there.

Comment: the complete code is working absolutely fine when I remove MAIN_PKG.PROC (v_run_no, 'v_job_id', SUBSTR (v_stream_id, 0, 2), 'v_file_name');  but it is not hitting the procedure at all else I would get another error which is handled inside that procedure.

Comment: Is the code you posted real? Why did you enclose 'v_job_id' and 'v_file_name' into single quotes? They are supposed to be variables, aren't they?

Comment: Are you sure the NDF is not raised from within the other procedure?  The exception handler for that procedure can raise the exception up the callstack (that is, all the way to your anonymous block).  I don't see how a procedure call itself could raise NO_DATA_FOUND so that's my best guess

Answer (score 0):

The only `SELECT` that can return `NO-DATA-FOUND` is this:

```
SELECT tbl.run_no,
       TBL.JOB_ID,
       TBL.STREAM_ID,
       TBL.FILE_NAME
  --INTO v_run_no,        -- intentionally commented
  --     v_job_id,
  --     v_stream_id,
  --     v_file_name
  FROM REGRESSION_STATUS tbl
       INNER JOIN (  SELECT job_id, MIN (run_no) min_run_no
                       FROM REGRESSION_STATUS
                      WHERE status = 'R'
                   GROUP BY job_id) tbl1
          ON tbl1.job_id = tbl.job_id
 WHERE     tbl1.min_run_no = tbl.run_no
       AND tbl.file_name LIKE '%A%';      --> or B / C / D
```

What happens when you run it *as is* (i.e. copy/paste the above code), possibly by changing the last line (A, B, C, D)? Can you verify that it really returns *something* (yes, I know - you said it does, but Oracle disagrees).

Comment: the complete code is working absolutely fine when I remove  MAIN_PKG.PROC (v_run_no,
                           'v_job_id',
                           SUBSTR (v_stream_id, 0, 2),
                           'v_file_name');

Comment: Aha, so error is raised within that procedure (PROC) in package (MAIN_PKG). You should investigate what it is doing and which SELECT raises the error.

Comment: no it not going inside that package too ... else I would have got error from log ...it is failing while it is passing the parameters only.

Comment: All the same, that is the most likely explanation. Perhaps `main_pkg.proc` uses an array in its declaration section or something.